# How should stack strings be initialized in C shellcode?

Tags: c, shellcode

I'm trying to optimize my [shellcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75212957/how-to-prevent-a-memory-leak-when-injecting-shellcode-into-another-process) by introducing a method to store strings as unit64_t values in an array. The shellcode project is written without any optimizations (Debug only) as I want to control everything at the opcode level i.e., the shellcode has precomputed offsets to local variables. If `/O2` optimizations were enabled, it might rearrange the C shellcode and mess things up?

For example, currently the shellcode has these stack arrays defined

```
char calc[]                     = { 'c','a','l','c','.','e','x','e',0 };
char winexec[]                  = { 'W','i','n','E','x','e','c',0 };
char sleep[]                    = { 'S','l','e','e','p',0 };
char createtoolhelp32snapshot[] = { 'C','r','e','a','t','e','T','o','o','l','h','e','l','p','3','2','S','n','a','p','s','h','o','t',0 };
char process32first[]           = { 'P','r','o','c','e','s','s','3','2','F','i','r','s','t',0 };
char process32next[]            = { 'P','r','o','c','e','s','s','3','2','N','e','x','t',0 };
char closehandle[]              = { 'C','l','o','s','e','H','a','n','d','l','e',0 };
char openprocess[]              = { 'O','p','e','n','P','r','o','c','e','s','s',0 };
char virtualallocex[]           = { 'V','i','r','t','u','a','l','A','l','l','o','c','E','x',0 };
char virtualfreeex[]            = { 'V','i','r','t','u','a','l','F','r','e','e','E','x',0 };
char writeprocessmemory[]       = { 'W','r','i','t','e','P','r','o','c','e','s','s','M','e','m','o','r','y',0 };
char createremotethread[]       = { 'C','r','e','a','t','e','R','e','m','o','t','e','T','h','r','e','a','d',0 };
char comparestringa[]           = { 'C','o','m','p','a','r','e','S','t','r','i','n','g','A',0};
char notepad[]                  = { 'n','o','t','e','p','a','d','.','e','x','e',0 };
char getcurrentprocessid[]      = { 'G','e','t','C','u','r','r','e','n','t','P','r','o','c','e','s','s','I','d',0 };
char exitthread[]               = { 'E','x','i','t','T','h','r','e','a','d',0 };
```

The generated assembly is

```
    52:     char calc[] = { 'c','a','l','c','.','e','x','e',0 };
00007FF6248B1C6D C6 45 08 63          mov         byte ptr [calc],63h  
00007FF6248B1C71 C6 45 09 61          mov         byte ptr [rbp+9],61h  
00007FF6248B1C75 C6 45 0A 6C          mov         byte ptr [rbp+0Ah],6Ch  
00007FF6248B1C79 C6 45 0B 63          mov         byte ptr [rbp+0Bh],63h  
00007FF6248B1C7D C6 45 0C 2E          mov         byte ptr [rbp+0Ch],2Eh  
00007FF6248B1C81 C6 45 0D 65          mov         byte ptr [rbp+0Dh],65h  
00007FF6248B1C85 C6 45 0E 78          mov         byte ptr [rbp+0Eh],78h  
00007FF6248B1C89 C6 45 0F 65          mov         byte ptr [rbp+0Fh],65h  
00007FF6248B1C8D C6 45 10 00          mov         byte ptr [rbp+10h],0  
    53:     char winexec[] = { 'W','i','n','E','x','e','c',0 };
00007FF6248B1C91 C6 45 38 57          mov         byte ptr [winexec],57h  
00007FF6248B1C95 C6 45 39 69          mov         byte ptr [rbp+39h],69h  
00007FF6248B1C99 C6 45 3A 6E          mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Ah],6Eh  
00007FF6248B1C9D C6 45 3B 45          mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Bh],45h  
00007FF6248B1CA1 C6 45 3C 78          mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Ch],78h  
00007FF6248B1CA5 C6 45 3D 65          mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Dh],65h  
00007FF6248B1CA9 C6 45 3E 63          mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Eh],63h  
00007FF6248B1CAD C6 45 3F 00          mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Fh],0
```

To improve performance, should those arrays be replaced with

```
    uint64_t calc[]                     = { 0x6578652e636c6163, 0x0000000000000000 };
    uint64_t winexec[]                  = { 0x00636578456e6957 };
    uint64_t sleep[]                    = { 0x0000007065656c53 };
    uint64_t createtoolhelp32snapshot[] = { 0x6f54657461657243, 0x3233706c65686c6f, 0x746f687370616e53, 0x0000000000000000 };
    uint64_t process32first[]           = { 0x33737365636f7250, 0x0000747372694632 };
    uint64_t process32next[]            = { 0x33737365636f7250, 0x0000007478654e32 };
    uint64_t closehandle[]              = { 0x6e614865736f6c43, 0x0000000000656c64 };
    uint64_t openprocess[]              = { 0x636f72506e65704f, 0x0000000000737365 };
    uint64_t virtualallocex[]           = { 0x416c617574726956, 0x00007845636f6c6c };
    uint64_t virtualfreeex[]            = { 0x466c617574726956, 0x0000007845656572 };
    uint64_t writeprocessmemory[]       = { 0x6f72506574697257, 0x6f6d654d73736563, 0x0000000000007972 };
    uint64_t createremotethread[]       = { 0x6552657461657243, 0x6572685465746f6d, 0x0000000000006461 };
    uint64_t comparestringa[]           = { 0x53657261706d6f43, 0x000041676e697274 };
    uint64_t notepad[]                  = { 0x2e64617065746f6e, 0x0000000000657865 };
    uint64_t getcurrentprocessid[]      = { 0x6572727543746547, 0x7365636f7250746e, 0x0000000000644973 };
    uint64_t exitthread[]               = { 0x6572685474697845, 0x0000000000006461 };
```

The generated assembly is

```
    71:     unsigned long long calc[] = { 0x6578652e636c6163, 0x0000000000000000 };
00007FF7EF7C1C5C 48 B8 63 61 6C 63 2E 65 78 65 mov         rax,6578652E636C6163h  
00007FF7EF7C1C66 48 89 45 08          mov         qword ptr [calc],rax  
00007FF7EF7C1C6A 48 C7 45 10 00 00 00 00 mov         qword ptr [rbp+10h],0  
    72:     unsigned long long winexec[] = {0x00636578456e6957};
00007FF7EF7C1C72 48 B8 57 69 6E 45 78 65 63 00 mov         rax,636578456E6957h  
00007FF7EF7C1C7C 48 89 45 38          mov         qword ptr [winexec],rax
```

**Question**

The shellcode works correctly with both definitions but is the extra performance worth degrading the readability?

**Tool**

https://godbolt.org/z/eYhWPG9E6

Comment: Shellcode does not need good performance. It is going to run once to exploit something and be done. The time to load the program in the first place will dwarf the tiny performance gains you might get from this.

Comment: True, as Eric noted in another post, with /O2 optimizations, the char based arrays are reduced to 64bit values, similar to the proposed array uint64_t values, so it's definitely faster, but in the grand scheme of things, probably insignificant.

Comment: really all this depend from compiler, optimization, array size and architecture ( x86, x64, arm64,.. ) this code can be wrong for your targets. for not depend from c/c++ implementation - use asm funcs for define strings. if use x64 (but not x86) - because most instruction here base independed, the access global strings - ie "xyz" - also will be base independed. you not need here in stack array at all. and in msvc we can control where code/data can be located. by using #pragma code_seg(".sc$code") and  #pragma const_seg(".sc$data") for instanse. possible another solutions too.